# Can HorizontalView And ScrollView Hold Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, horizontalscrollview

I just would like to ask if these Layouts can hold fragment/multiple fragments. I base this on google play store.

Sorry for bad logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, scroll views can hold multiple fragments.

**However**, managing the fragment stack gets tricky.

Because fragmentManager/ChildFragmentManager will only maintain stack for one container, if I am not wrong.

As long as you don't add them dynamically in run time,it is easy.

i.e. if the fragments are described in the scroll view from xml layout and you don't perform fragment transactions, you are all good.

I have dealt with the same issue, and cost me a lot of trouble but I did implement it. However, if you end up with such a requirement, you might be doing something wrong give other solutions a go and see if you can avoid this requirement.

**NOTE :** I don't think Google play uses fragments in Scroll Views.
What I see them do is have RecyclerViews within recycler views, if this is what you are talking about[image]

i.e. There are Horizontal RecyclerViews within Vertical RecyclerViews.

In case you are not aware, RecyclerViews are the new version of listViews, they are more powerful and perform way better.

I suggest you don't use listViews, but use RecyclerViews instead.

Comment: Thank you making that one clear to me, I realized that also. Setting the Layout in RecyclerView to Horizontal. The root is using DrawerLayout-CoordinationLayout-AppbarLayout-- So on. Can you clarify this one to me, It recycle fragments and in the fragments it recycle the cardviews within it?

Comment: So what you will have is a fragment or activity as root. Then in that root's XML layout, you will add a recyclerView.  In that recycler view, you will have items called ViewHolders. These view holders are just views, you can add anything there, what play app has done is, in each viewHolder, they put recyclerViews(horizontal). You will have to read upon on RecyclerView and implement one or two and play around with it, before you attempt to do play store like example, or you will just be confused.