# RecyclerView inside another RecyclerView ( new into developing)

Tags: android

so right now Im trying to have a recyclerview with multiple views, view one type: TextView, view two type:RecyclerView.

[How I want the ui to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60FGa.png)

So am i going for the right approach, to create an adatper with two types of views, one for textview, and another as recyclerview and pass list of strings to the the inside recyclerview's adapter? or is there something im missing

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean ?

You have on recyclerview, which can have a recyclerview inside it, as a viewholder type? If that is what you mean, yes it is possible and it is not a problem.

I recommend you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37192563/4127441). The question in link is about a recycler view with fragments in it, but it does explain some similar concepts.

That being said, if the only thing that is dynamic or non pre determinable, are the checkboxes, but you know before hand the number and position of every other element there are two solutions

**Solution 1:**

```
<scrollView>
   <TextView1>
   <TextView2>
   <TextView3>
   <RecyclerView1>
</scrollView>
```

The `scrollView` scrolls vertically, the `textViews` are static/ hard coded as you know how and what they are.

`RecyclerView1` is a recycler view that shows the dynamic `checkboxes`.
The check boxes are in a recycler view, because you said they are dynamic and you don't know their size before hand, you can use nested scrolling to handle vertical scrolls in `recyclerView1`

**Solution 2:**

This is very similar to what you have in mind.

You have only one recycler view.
It has two type of view holders, one holds all the text views.
The other holds one check box.
So your recycler view checks if the data is a checkbox, if it is not, it shows the `textview view holder` otherwise it shows a `checkbox view holder`
So you might end up with something like this when you render the recyclerview :

```
<TextViewsViewHolder>
<CheckboxViewHolder>
<CheckboxViewHolder>
<CheckboxViewHolder>
<CheckboxViewHolder>
```

The `TextViewsViewHolder` will have all your text views and `CheckboxViewHolder` holds a check box each. 
I recommend solution2, which is basically same similar to what you said, but there is only one recycler view in total.

Comment: Thank you, I needed to make sure i was on the right track before starting working on it, yea im keeping it dynamic in case i want to add new questions or something, i can do it from the backend instead of changing it from the app

Comment: Glad to help. Appreciate an up vote on the answer when you get up vote  the privilege.

Comment: I am so sorry, the first answer I gave you was wrong! I have updated with the right solution, which is much simpler, please use the updated version of the solution.

Comment: But how would this checkboxes be grouped together? if its going to be different cell item

Comment: recycler view helps you draw dynamic views. So in your rv can draw two type of views, one view holds all the textviews, the other can draw a single checkbox, so in the `getItemViewType()` you can determine which type of view to draw, so in that method, if the position in 0, draw textview view, other wise draw checkbox view.

Comment: For the cells to not look like separate cells, don't use decorators and in your xml don't use any views/attributes to add any effect of visual separation. Try it, I use this in many places in our production app.